# xConnectCollection Error using Azure SQL as Backend

Tags: xconnect

I have Azure VMs (Iaas) running Sitecore 9 Update 1 and am using Azure SQL as my backend. I deployed the xConnect Shards using the Shard Map Manager and it showed as successful. However, despite doing all the post steps of rebuilding links, indexes, and deploying marketing definitions without error, I keep getting the following error without data showing in Experience Analytics:

> 2018-07-03 14:19:14.811 -07:00 [Error] XConnect Exception Logger
>   LogAsync() Sitecore.Xdb.Processing.Queue.ProcessingPoolException:
>   Could not find stored procedure
>   'xdb_processing_pools.InteractionLiveProcessing_AddBatch'. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure
>   'xdb_processing_pools.InteractionLiveProcessing_AddBatch'.

Comment: I would start with obvious does xconnect have the correct connection strings for the processing pools db? Have you verified that your Processing.Pools database has a stored procedure called "xdb_processing_pools.InteractionLiveProcessing_AddBatch"?

Comment: Can you check permissions for user which you have specified in ConnectionStrings.config? Probably this is "poolsuser". Check whether this user has Execute and Connect permissions for that database. Try to login through SSMS as this user to see what effective access it has.

Comment: Poolsuser has connect and execute, and the connectionStrings are correct. However, the stored procedures do look completely different than my on-prem build. I will investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the Pools database lacking the stored procedures. A re-import of the pools database bacpac to Azure SQL fixed the issue.